I want to slide the View from left to right and also it should disappear be from left to right in swift
func createAnimationView() -> UIView {
    let animationView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 60))
    animationView.backgroundColor = .red
   
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, animations: {
         animationView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -animationView.frame.width, y: 0)
    }) { _ in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5) {
            animationView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: animationView.frame.width, y: 0)
        }
    }
    
    return animationView
}

This is not working as expected. first its sliding from right to left and disappearing from left to right.
I want it to be first slide from left to right. Can anyone please help here.
Thanks in Advance..

To clarify: You want your view to start off-screen to the left ... slide in from left to right ... then continue to slide off the screen to the right? Or, slide in from left to right then slide back out from right to left?

slide in from left to right then slide back out from right to left

You need to start with the view's .frame.origin.x as a negative value of its width. You can then transform its .origin.x by positive width, followed by negative width:
func createAnimationView() -> UIView {
    let animationView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 60))
    
    // start off-screen to the left
    animationView.frame.origin.x = -animationView.frame.width
    
    animationView.backgroundColor = .red
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, animations: {
        // animate in from left-to-right
        animationView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: animationView.frame.width, y: 0)
    }) { _ in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5) {
            // animate out from right-to-left
            animationView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -animationView.frame.width, y: 0)
        }
    }
    
    return animationView
}

